# Python str to dict

Tags: python

Есть файл, в фале строки вида:

```
'code':'DHCP-Discover/Offer' 'xid':'914729774' 'sw':'sint-2et_igor_2' 'port':'1'    'vlan':'2001' 'mac':'cc:b2:55:5f:eb:dc' 'venid':'"dslforum.org"' 'ip':'46.43.224.1' 'status':'ok'
```

Вопрос как из строки получить словарь?

Answer (score 4):

Что-то вроде такого.

```
diction = dict(map((lambda substr: substr.split(":")), str.split(" ")))
```

Кавычки, естественно, можно заранее вычистить.